# Converting seconds into Hours, Minutes, and Seconds in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I want to set a Cooldown for my Discord Bot, here's the code :

```
    if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }
    
    const now = Date.now();
    const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 3) * 1000;

    if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
    const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;

    if (now < expirationTime) {
        const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) % 3600 / 60
        return message.reply(`please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} Hours before reusing the \`${command.name}\` command.`);
    }
}

timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);
```

The delay for the command is '86400' / 24 Hours, but the output shows 36.2 hours instead of 24 hours. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subracting the two dates will give you the difference in `ms`.
For calculating the difference in `hours` you should use:

```
 const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000 / 3600;
```

Note that if you're planning to do more sophisticated date arithmetic I recommend using a library like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Thanks, just figured out that i need to convert it into miliseconds, i though it was already seconds, thank you so much